# A conjecture about “equiharmonic numbers” of Flajolet via Doron Zeilberger

Tags: generating-functions, continued-fractions

While semi-randomly browsing,
I came across this conjecture
which Philippe Flajolet
sent to Doron Zeilberger
as a "gift" 
(the "gift" is here,
so you can check to see
if I have typeset it correctly):
http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/fp09.pdf
):

GIFT. Define the “equiharmonic numbers” by
$$K_ν 
:= \frac{(6ν)!}{Ω^{6ν}}
\sum\limits_
{(n_1,n_2)∈(Z×Z)-{(0,0)}}
\frac1{(n_1e^{−2iπ/3} + n_2e^{2iπ/3})^{6ν}}
, Ω :=
\frac1{2π}
Γ(1/3)^3
.
$$

Show that
the generating function of 
$(K_ν)$
 admits the continued fraction representation
$$\frac{7}{36}
\sum\limits_{ν≥1}
K_νz^{ν−1}
 = 
\frac{1}{1 − 
\dfrac{d_1 · z}{1 − 
\dfrac{d_2 · z}{...}
}}
$$
where $d_1 = \frac{10880}{13}$ , 
$d_2 = \frac{13810240}{247}$, 
$d_n = \frac14
\frac{(3n)(3n + 1)^2(3n + 2)^2(3n + 3)^2(3n + 4)}
{(6n + 1)(6n + 7)}
$ .

I have absolutely no idea
how to even begin attacking
this conjecture.
It looks like something
Ramanujan might have come up with.
A search for
“equiharmonic numbers”
was futile.

Does anyone have any idea
how this might be attacked
or, even better,
if this has been solved?

Comment: I'd look at $\wp(z,\Lambda)$ for $\Lambda=\zeta_3\mathbb{Z}+\zeta_3^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$ with $\zeta_3=\exp\frac{2\pi\mathrm{i}}{3}$. The coefficients are Eisenstein series and $\tau=\zeta_3$ whence $G_k(\Lambda)=0$ for all $k$ not divisible by $6$.

Comment: How would I search for "$\wp(z,\Lambda)$"? It looks to me like a Weierstrass Elliptic Function, but, after having looked it up, it seems beyond my pay grade. If you can make any sort of start on this, I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: There are some typos in the `fp09.pdf`: $d_1=\frac{10800}{13}, d_2=\frac{3810240}{247}$, consistent with the formula for $d_n$. With these corrections, the formula holds at least up to $d_{99}$ as tested with Pari/GP.